# Excel SOLVER: how to do optimization with the constraints predetermined

Tags: excel, solver

I try to minimize the sum of the cell value.
Subtraction of (constant value - predetermined  constraints) sums up.
The snippet below may explain more clearly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfqCX.png)

I am not sure how to select the value from predetermined constraint list and reorder while accomplishing the objective.

Comment: A helper column set to binary being the decision variables in the solver then sumproduct()

Comment: Binary method solves this problem? All values needs selecting and ordering.